gpg failing in Ubuntu 22.04
I want to sign some PDFs using gpg command. I have my GnuPG key generated in "Passwords and Keys" GUI. Now, if I do
gpg --clearsign --output=signed_doc.pdf doc.pdf

the output is graphically distorted in such a way that it becomes non recognizable anymore (e.g. the text disappears, weird and very large black things appear, etc). If I do instead an invisible signature with
gpg --sign --output=signed_doc.pdf doc.pdf

now I cannot open the PDFs anymore with the PDF reader, and get File type unknown (application/octet-stream) is not supported.
How can I digitally sign the documents?

What set the expectation that you could digitally sign a PDF this way? Typically you want to separate the gpg signature from the file. As explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215959/1610
